# How to sort table returned in AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, sorting

I have the following AJAX call to a PHP page to get data from the database to show it in a table in HTML page. I want `#OrderTable` to be sortable.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "searchorders.php",
  data: {
    'OrderBy': OrderBy,
    'StartDate': startDate,
    'EndDate': endDate
  },
  success: function(data) {
    if (data == "Failed") {
      $('#NoData').append("No data Found!");
    } else {
      $('#OrderTable').append(data);
      document.getElementById("Results").style.display = 'block';
      **$('#SearchResults').DataTable();**
    }
  }
})
```

Part of my table in PHP page

```
$output.='<hr />
    <table id="SearchResults" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:auto;">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Order No.</th>
        <th>Customer Name</th>
        <th>Order Date</th>
        <th>Category Name</th>
        <th>Category Type</th>
        <th>Quantity in Kilos</th>
        <th>Delivery Date</th>
        <th>Order Status</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    ';
```

Comment: get records order by and display returned records to the table

Comment: Use `order by` in your `SQL` all the data received will be sorted.

Comment: I need the user to sort it himself according to his choice of column on live time

Comment: check out datatables https://datatables.net/

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou, i used it but it shows the arrows only without sorting, if you can help me in that or if you have used it before

Comment: @NewPHP What did you try? Update your Question with what you tryied so far

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou, i updated it,check plz

Answer (score 0):

Use order by query in your sql code itself i.e in your searchorder.php itself and then show the data returing from there